# Trouble with YouTube API search

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using this code:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?q=global+warming&part=id&maxResults=50&key=MY-KEY-HERE
```

and it's returning 50 results, but I'd like it to look for videos that have been closed captioned and also I'd like to get the video's titles as well. I also can't figure out how to get the next page of search results.

for captions I tried adding **&videoCaption=closedCaption** but got an error saying

```
""reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
    "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions."
```

I also tried adding "nextPageToken=CDIQAA" since that's the token i got on the original search but i end up getting the exact same search results.

Can someone help me get what I need out of the search?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that I need to use **pageToken=CDIQAA** instead of **nextPageToken**, so at least I have that part.

Adding **&type=video & videoCaption=closedCaption** seems to return nothing but videos that have been closed captioned, as I wanted.